# Grid/Model Fail When Binary Data Stored In Column

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, model

> Preface: I know it's not best-practice to store binary data in the database.  It's a simple and cheap solution to provide the same file across our distributed servers without relying upon a single NFS.

I've got a custom model, and model repository, that when saving it will allow you to upload a binary file (specifically a PKCS12 certificate and key bundle).  The binary data is then extracted and placed into the database correctly.  I can query the DB directly and see that the data is in fact there.

When I go to look at the grid (or edit the record) I have to remove the binary column from the select to get the data to show up.  If I leave the binary data in, then there comes a javascript error relating to invalid JSON because the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` key doesn't have a value.

I know I can base64 encode the data, which is what I will most likely do, but is there a way the model could load the binary data but not include it in the KnockoutJS configuration object?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just base64 encoding the data stored in the database.